# Removing cout statement causing value change of a variable

Tags: c++, gcc, cout

In the following code, when I'm removing cout statement (line after //******)then it is causing a change in the value of "i".
I used TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32 bit release and TDM-GCC 5.1.0 compilers.
I ran this code on codechef and there it runs fine and cout statement is not affecting the value of "i".

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int subset(int [], int);
int main()
{
    int size,i,ans;
    cout<<"size of array : ";
    cin>>size;
    int arr[size];
    for(i = 0 ; i<size;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    ans = subset(arr,size);
    cout<<"ans = "<<ans;

    return 0;

}
int subset(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i,j, tsum=0, completed=0;
    for(i = 0 ;i<size;i++)
        tsum = tsum + arr[i];

    int carr[tsum+1],temp;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        carr[temp] = 1;
        for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
        {
            temp = temp + arr[j];
            carr[temp] = 1;
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=tsum;i++)
    {
        if(carr[i]!=1)
        {
            //************************************
            cout<<"i : "<<i<<endl; 
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;

}
```

Sample input : 
size of array : 3

1
2
5

sample output without cout statement :

ans = 6

sample output having cout statement :

i : 4

ans = 4

Actual answere is 4 for the input.

Comment: Technically your code is not valid C++ code, as C++ doesn't really have [variable-lenght arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: And this seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: While your code has a number of issues like using C-style variable length arrays that aren't valid C++, running it gives me 4 both with and without that line commented out.

Comment: Spoiler alert: You will find in the debugger, that your actual problem is not the `cout` you suspect but the statement in next line... Are you aware of the effect of `break`s in  a `for` loop?

Comment: @Shawn, which compiler are you using ?

Comment: And if the result depends on compiler, then you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)!

Comment: @AkhileshAgrahari gcc and clang. I don't think MSVC++ will compile it because of the VLAs. If you're expecting that to return something besides 4 for your given input, you should say so in your post...

Comment: please, could anyone give me a valid code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that `carr` is uninitialized.

It is declared as

```
int carr[tsum+1]
```

with no initializer.

Later on some elements are set, but always to `1`:

```
    carr[temp] = 1;
```

In the last loop `carr` is examined:

```
    if(carr[i]!=1)
```

This condition makes no sense. Either `carr[i]` has been set, then it is guaranteed to be `1`, or it is uninitialized, in which case this comparison has undefined behavior.

---

Note that variable-length arrays are not standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problems as stated by *Some Programmer Dude* and *melpomene*, i.e. Variable-length arrays are not standard C++ and `carr` is uninitialized. Use c++ vectors and initialize them correctly. That would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int subset(const std::vector<int>, const int);
int main()
{
    int size, i, ans;
    cout << "size of array : ";
    cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> arr(size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    ans = subset(arr, size);
    cout << "ans = " << ans;

    return 0;

}
int subset(const std::vector<int> arr, const int size)
{
    int i, j, tsum = 0, completed = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tsum = tsum + arr[i];

    std::vector<int> carr(tsum + 1, 0);
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        carr[temp] = 1;
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            temp = temp + arr[j];
            carr[temp] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= tsum; i++)
    {
        if (carr[i] != 1)
        {
            //************************************
            cout << "i : " << i << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;

}
```